# DOTCMIS with Alfresco 3.1

Tags: alfresco, dotcmis

I have Alfrsco 3.1 implementation. Can I use DOTCMIS.dll with this version? If yes, from where I can download the same?
Please reply asap.

Thanks,

Comment: what do you mean by "the same"?

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco 3.1 supports [a draft version of CMIS](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Enterprise_3.1#Alfresco_Draft_CMIS_Implementation), against CMIS v0.5.

The various libraries in [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/) currently (March 2013) all support CMIS v1.0, with a few of them also supporting some of the CMIS v1.1 draft features. There's some support for older, draft versions of the spec, but everyone generally runs with v1.0 implementations.

Alfresco 3.1 is pretty old, so I'd strongly suggest you upgrade. The most recent versions of Alfresco support CMIS v1.0 very well, and you'll have no problems using DotCMIS with it. If you do decide to stick with your old Alfresco, I'd expect it'll largely work...

Comment: Hi Gagravarr,
Thanks for your valuable comments. 
Unfortunately, I will have to run with the older version 3.1.0. I have tried DOTCMIS for Alfresco 4.2 (the latest one), and it worked as desired. I downloaded the .dll from http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html

But now, I have to develop a .NET application which will communicate with 3.1
Hence, what is the best approach you suggest for? Are web services supported here?
Appreciate for your kind help..

Comment: Why do you need to run the older version? It's a very odd version to target anyway... There are some webservices in 3.1, and some RESTful webscripts, you'll be best off reviewing the 3.1 enterprise docs and webscript service listings and go from there. Or, upgrade! To something at least from this decade...

Comment: For the reason that I want to migrate the data from Alfreso 3.1.0 to different ECM product, i will have to develop custom .NET application which will extract the data using CMIS APIs and export it.
Kindly suggest some approach. Thanks.

Comment: Why not upgrade your repo to Alfresco 4.1 (or 4.2 community)? You can the use that with DotCMIS to fetch the data out. Just drop in the new war file and Alfresco will auto-upgrade the data